# How do I call BCP from powershell using parameters passed in through .net?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following c# code:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
            powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
            powerShell.AddArgument(connectionString);
            powerShell.AddArgument(storedProc);
            powerShell.AddArgument(dataSource);
            powerShell.AddArgument(filterList);
            powerShell.AddArgument(destinationFile);
            var script = "path\to\the\powershell.ps1";
            powerShell.AddScript(script);
            powerShell.Invoke();
```

And I want it to work with this powershell script:

```
$connString = $args[0]
$spName = $args[1]
$dataSource = $args[2]
$filterList = $args[3]
$destinationFile = $args[4]
bcp "$spName $filterList" queryout "$destinationFile" -c -t"\0" $connString
```

I have NO experience with powershell. Does this look right to you guys and gals? What about the .NET code. Would that run the script like I'm assuming?

Answer (score 0):

Your C# needs some tweaking. First, you can't add arguments until you have added a command. Second, the AddScript() method wants the script contents of Powershell.ps1 - not the path. Try this:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
var script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\the\powershell.ps1");
ps.AddScript(script)
ps.AddArgument(connectionString);
ps.AddArgument(storedProc);
ps.AddArgument(dataSource);
ps.AddArgument(filterList);
ps.AddArgument(destinationFile);
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I've made the changes you suggested. I'm glad you made them because I wasn't really paying that much attention to me C#. Do you know if those variables in the poewrshell work that way? Specifically, surrounding them with quotes like that?

Comment: Ah yeah, path \ chars need to be escaped or use a verbatim string.  I updated the answer to use a verbatim string.